# ConfigParser and 2 config files

Tags: python

I want to split my config file to 2 config files: common.conf and particular.conf. It's possible parse 2 config files as one config ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just pass all the filenames to `configparser`. It's in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.read):

> Attempt to read and parse a list of filenames, returning a list of
>   filenames which were successfully parsed. If filenames is a string or
>   Unicode string, it is treated as a single filename. If a file named in
>   filenames cannot be opened, that file will be ignored. This is
>   designed so that you can specify a list of potential configuration
>   file locations (for example, the current directory, the user’s home
>   directory, and some system-wide directory), and all existing
>   configuration files in the list will be read. If none of the named
>   files exist, the ConfigParser instance will contain an empty dataset.
>   An application which requires initial values to be loaded from a file
>   should load the required file or files using readfp() before calling
>   read() for any optional files:
>
> ```
> import ConfigParser, os
>
> config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
> config.readfp(open('defaults.cfg'))
> config.read(['site.cfg', os.path.expanduser('~/.myapp.cfg')])
> ```
>
> Changed in version 2.4: Returns list of successfully parsed filenames.